# Cómo podría ejecutar una función después que el GridView se haya modificado?

Tags: javascript, mvc, devexpress

Estoy usando el evento `batchEditApi.EndEdit` pero al momento de ejecutarlo no hace ninguna acción, lo que quiero es que se actualice el grid primero y luego realice la función `Modificar()`... ya que cuando coloco la función fuera de la condición primero se ejecuta esta y luego modifica el GridView.
Al parecer este evento solo funciona cuando termino de editar la celda y no después de guardar cambios.

```js
function GridUpdate(s, e) {
    ASPxClientGridView.Cast("grid_FormaPago").UpdateEdit();
    if (ASPxClientGridView.Cast("grid_FormaPago").batchEditApi.EndEdit()) {
        Modificar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pregunté en foro de DevExpress y me respondieron que se puede realizar utilizando el evento `ASPxClientGridView.EndCallback`

```js
var flag = false;
function CambioMonto(s, e) { 
     ASPxClientGridView.Cast("grid_FormaPago").UpdateEdit();
     flag = true;
}

function onEndCallback(s,e){
     if (flag){
          Modificar(); //Not Working
          flag = false;
     }
}
```